# Permission Denied Database on Windows phone

Tags: c#, permissions, windows-phone

I got this error when Add data to database (on windows phone app) at this line :

```
if (concac.DatabaseExists())
{
   concac.Cacs.InsertOnSubmit(fullname);
   concac.SubmitChanges();
}
```

And this is the error:

```
{System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Permission denied.
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeResultSet.InternalInsert(Boolean fMoveTo, Object sender, SqlCeUpdatableRecord record)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeResultSet.Insert(SqlCeUpdatableRecord record, DbInsertOptions options)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DoResultSetInsert(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
   at Member.DBHelper.AddName(Cac1 fullname)
   at Member.Add.appBarOkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarItemContainer.FireEventHandler(EventHandler handler, Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButtonContainer.ClickEvent()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar.OnCommand(UInt32 idCommand, Boolean isButton)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.NativeCallbackInteropWrapper.OnCommand(UInt32 idCommand, Boolean isButton)}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have permission(s) to the database you are trying to access? The error is _quite_ clear to me.

Comment: ok. i get mistake.  i set File mode = read only... so i can add data to this. thanks ur help

Comment: Did that fix the problem?  If it did, let me add it as an answer so you can mark it.

Comment: yep. everything is ok right now...

Comment: I have added an answer.  Please accept/up vote.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need to check permissions on your DB. As an example, in MSSQL, you have to grant permissions (per user) when using a SELECT or UPDATE statement.